# How to change bubble color in legend and create more space between these bubbles in legend layout?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a bubble plot but I am not able to change the color of the bubbles in my legend. How could I change it to green as I did in my plot?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0.1, 100, 10, 25, 150],
                  "x":[1, 1.5, 1.3, 2, 1.1],
                  "y":[0.1, 0.2, 0.13, 0.15, 0.16]})

plt.figure()
sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", size="a", color="green", sizes=(10, 1000), data=df, alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
```

[image]

And the other thing is that these bubbles in the legend overlap each other. Is there a way to create space between them to show their sizes in a cleaner way?

Comment: I think the following methods will help a little.`plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, labelspacing=3.0)`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @r-beginners . Do you have any tips to change the color of the bubbles inside the legend?

Comment: If you stop setting color and add a hue setting, the scatter and legend will be color-coded. `sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", size="a", hue="a", sizes=(10, 1000), data=df, alpha=0.5)`